# Newbie: How to set attribute of the relative layout in my case?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-widget

I would like to divide my screen into 4 equal areas like **田**.Each one of the four area is a linear layout.

I tried to use **relative layout** to hold four **linear layout** like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/up_left_area"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ffff66"
    >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/label1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="UP LEFT"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/up_right_area"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/up_left_area"
        android:background="#ccffff">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/label2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="UP RIGHT"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/down_left_area"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/up_left_area"
        android:background="#66cc33"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/label3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="DOWN LEFT"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/down_right_area"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/up_right_area"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/down_left_area"
         android:background="#cc6600">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/label4"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="DOWN RIGHT"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

With the above xml layout code, I do get 4 areas on the screen, but they are **not** equal sized. How to modify my code to have **equal sized 4 areas** on the screen like **田** ？

Comment: Tip: if you don't have anything else inside the `LinearLayout`s beside the `TextViews`s, you might consider refactoring your code to put the `TextViews` directly in the `RelativeLayout`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could use linear layouts with the same layout_weight=1.

simplified xml:

```
- linearlayout orientation=vertical, layout_width=fill_parent, layout_height=fill_parent
 -- linearLayout orientation=horizontal, layout_weight=1, layout_width=fill_parent, layout_height=fill_parent
 -- -- linearLayout layout_weight=1, layout_width=fill_parent, layout_height=fill_parent
 -- -- -- .... LEFT TOP
 -- -- linearLayout layout_weight=1, layout_width=fill_parent, layout_height=fill_parent
 -- -- -- .... RIGHT TOP
 -- linearLayout orientation=horizontal, layout_weight=1, layout_width=fill_parent, layout_height=fill_parent
 -- -- linearLayout layout_weight=1, layout_width=fill_parent, layout_height=fill_parent
 -- -- -- .... LEFT BOTTOM
 -- -- linearLayout layout_weight=1, layout_width=fill_parent, layout_height=fill_parent
 -- -- -- .... RIGHT BOTTOM
```

... something like that.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `RelativeLayout` as root layout, a trick could be to add a

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/center_of_screen"
    android:layout_height="1px"
    android:layout_width="1px"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"></FrameLayout>
```

So you'd know the center of the screen, and then align the 4 `LinearLayouts` using combinations of `toRightOf, toLeftOf, below`and`above` layout atributes :).

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend you to use `LinearLayout` as a root layout. You can choose, whether orientation will be `vertical` or `horizontal`, but I don't think it matters here. Then you create two `LinearLayouts` and set their `android:layout_height` (if orientation is vertical) or `android:layout_width` (if orientation is horizontal) property to `fill_parent`, and their `android:layout_weight` property to `"1"`. This way you'll divide your screen on two equal parts. Same thing you should do to divide those 2 parts on 2 parts each. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

According to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html, the dimensions can either be `fill_parent`, `wrap_content` or a specific number of pixels. you can use `Display.getWidth()` and `Display.getHeight()` and pass in half of that to LayoutParams.

I'm not sure if theres a way to do that directly in the XML, though that would be much more elegant.